# Delay when using ApiGateway

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

I'm a backend developer, and I've developed a WebApi service with `Asp.Net Core`.
I've also developed `ApiGateway` using `Ocelot` library.

From front side, front-end developers use `React` and `Axios` as HTTP client.

When the request is provided to the API method directly, it works nice.
But when the request is called through the `ApiGateway`, response time is much bigger (more than 1-2 minutes).
This delay is performed from `Chromium-based` browsers f.e: `Google Chrome`, `Microsoft Edge` and `Opera`.
Everything is OK from `Mozilla Firefox`.

Also, there is no any problem from `Postman` and `JMeter`.

What can be a reason of a such behavior? 
Or where should I try to find a solution, on the back or front side?

Answer (score 1):

> With API Gateway it requires going from the client to API Gateway,
> which means leaving the application and going out to the internet,
> then back to your application to go to your other Instance, then back
> to API Gateway, which means leaving your application again and then
> back to your first instance.
>
> So this additional latency is expected. The only way to lower the
> latency is to add in API Caching which is only going to be useful is
> if the content you are requesting is going to be static and not
> updating constantly. You will still see the longer latency when the
> item is removed from cache and needs to be fetched from the System,
> but it will lower most calls.

So I guess the latency is normal, which is unfortunate.

As for why it responds well on Mozilla Firefox, probably due to [differences between API implementations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Differences_between_API_implementations).

The above is my point of view, I hope it will help you. If my understanding is wrong, please correct me, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think rerouting slows down the process because it works fine with Postman.
As for the information about the browsers, it sounds interesting, it might be helpful.