# API Delay when using Gateway only on DEV Server

Tags: angular, iis, .net-6.0, api-gateway

This issue was already discussed before in this post [Delay when using ApiGateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403614/delay-when-using-apigateway).

In my case its a little bit different scenario.

I am working with microservices architecture
with multiple WEB API Projects in .NET 6 and API Gateway with Ocelot.
Front-end is developed angular.

I have 2 servers (DEV & PROD).
One is located in America, Dallas **(Server A)** and
other is in Asia, Singapore **(Server B)**.

Same piece of code is working fine on **(Server A)** but not working on **(Server B)**.
But I am only getting API Delay on **(Server B)**.

I have tried so many things like

- IIS Request Monitoring.
- System Event Viewer.
- IIS Configuration for Websites and their APP Pools.
- Leansentry Software to monitor IIS traffic.
- Latency Test.

none of the above works or found any hang or delay issue.

Interesting part is there is no delay when using Postman or Mozilla Firefox.

My question is why I am not getting any API delay on **(Server A)**.
I should get delay on both servers right ?

I am so confused any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Is the API on Server A being accessed more frequently? This will cause them to be cached or kept in memory, resulting in faster response times. Also, if the API on Server B is not being accessed frequently, it may need to be "warmed up", resulting in slower initial response times.

Comment: Yes API traffic is greater on Server A than Server B. I think "Warmed up" is not a issue because first 3 to 5 calls work great but after that API call give a response between 1-2 mins and in that moment if i try to call any other API's they all get stuck and return response between 1-2 mins.

Comment: Basically I bought a new server and moved my old Dev server to new. I installed everything from scratch. The same environment is working fine on old Dev server and Prod but having issues in new Dev server. I don't know why. rite now we are using Mozilla Firefox for development API's are working fine on this expect other google chrome.

Comment: If the problem is prominent on Google Chrome but not on Mozilla Firefox, so it might have something to do with how Chrome handles the request. Now it only allows for guessing, there may be browser-specific issues, such as extensions interfering with requests or differences in how browsers handle caching.
Disable all Chrome extensions and test the API request again. Sometimes browser extensions can interfere with network requests and cause delays or problems.

Comment: if this has to do with "how Chrome handles the requests" then why i am not getting any issue on my prod server ? Same piece of code is deployed on both only have one difference is that server location are different.

Comment: Since data must be routed through the network, the physical location of the server may affect response times. If the majority of your users are in the United States, a request to server A might have a shorter route than a request to server B in Asia.

Comment: so is there any solution ?? I have an option to change my server location to different region but i have to install everything from start. I will try this solution if don't find any other solution.